# de una consulta PHP a Objeto Android Studio

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

Soy estudiante y lo que quiero hacer en si, es saber como convertir la consulta obtenida a partir de una peticion PHP, mediante una funcion retornar un Objeto
El JSON que se genera a partir de la consulta es el siguiente :

```
[{"idjugador":"7","cedula":"1101","nombres":"Carlos","apellidos":"Juca","contrasenia":"1234","estado":"1","funcion":"1","posicion":"Jungla","nivelClasificatoria":"Hierro","nickName":"chjuca"}]
```